# Specify Markdown code language as JAVA, got strange views

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-pages

I am writing a blog about React on github page with jekyll.

But I found mark the JSX code is very difficult. If I specified the code language as javascript, jekyll will not highlight the code. If I specified the code language as java, jekyll highlight the code, but got a strange result.

Any suggestion about markdown JSX?

[image]

[image]

Not work even I change the language to Javascript. I got the following result:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitHub Pages [use](https://help.github.com/articles/using-syntax-highlighting-on-github-pages/) [Rouge](https://github.com/jneen/rouge) for syntax highlighting. Unfortunately, it [does not currently support JSX as a language](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/wiki/List-of-supported-languages-and-lexers). There is an [open issue to add support for JSX](https://github.com/jneen/rouge/issues/275).

But it isn't surprising that Java code highlighting doesn't give the results you want: your code *isn't* Java. It's much closer to Java​*Script*. These are two almost entirely unrelated languages, and JavaScript is a much better choice in this case:

````
```javascript
// ...
```
````

I would use this for now and update it when JSX support is added to Rouge.

Comment: Even javascript not work for me. I updated my question and add another screenshot

Comment: @shi, of course JavaScript won't work perfectly, but it's closer than Java. JSX is basically a hybrid of JavaScript and SGML. Because it's not supported by Rouge yet you'll have to live with partial support (or use no highlighting at all).